# How to get a DbDataReader object directly in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, dbdatareader

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx), there is an object called `DbDataReader` that is created in the process of running a SQL query in Entity Framework.

Entity Framework "translates" the `DbDataReader` into a entity class.

How can I access the DbDataReader directly?

Comment: I was hoping that there is some way to access the values returned from SQL directly while still having the benefit of having EF manage connections and all the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data reader it if you execute the query yourself:

```
using (var command = context.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ...3;
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of works.  I'm disappointed to see that I still must manually open and close the connections, tho.